# Youtube player force playlist dropdown to open

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

Does any body know, how to force a playlists dropdown to open in an embeded youtube player. I have an iframe with HTML5 youtube video player in it and I load the playlists dynamically.
I want the dropdown to open, when playlist is changed. I tried to create a click event inside an iframe, but console says that it is not allowed. I also didn't find any functions in their reference.

Comment: You can not touch the iframe. [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Is there any other way to manually open playlist dropdown panel?